# Dijkstra on 2D grid?

Tags: point, dijkstra

There are N points on a 2D grid (x,y). I need to find the shortest path, from point A to point  B, but I can only travel from one point to another and I can't travel between two points if the distance between them is farther than a distance D. I thought it might be solved by using some kind of modified Dijkstra's algorithm, but I'm not sure how, because I've never implemented it before, just studied it on Wiki.

Comment: use Dijkstra's algorithm stopping at a node (instead of considering its unvisited neighbours) when D is exceeded

Comment: But how would I implement that ? Can a 2d grid be interpreted as a graph ?

Comment: It's an implicit graph in which each square of the grid is a vertex and two vertices have an edge between them if their corresponding grid squares are adjacent.

Comment: You can also think of each point on the grid as a vertex and the lines connecting to points vertically or horizontally as edges.  If it's a perfect grid, the cost between edges would be constant.

Comment: Well, you can even travel diagonally, if the distance is lesser than D. So I suppose the edges don't have to be just horizontal or vertical.

Comment: @CLU it depends on your definition of grid and (importantly) distance - maybe you could describe those better. What is the distance between to points? Which points are connected?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Dijkstra finds shortest paths in graphs.  So just consider the grid points to be nodes in a graph with edges between each node S and all other nodes T such that dist(S, T) <= D.  You don't have to actually construct the graph because the edges are easily determined as needed by Dijkstra.  Just check all nodes in a square around S with radius D.  A S-T edge exists iff (Sx - Tx)^2 (Sy - Ty)^2 <= D^2.

Comment: This guy is a beginner. So let him construct the graph :)

Comment: What about the time complexity ? Can I assume that Dijkstra can find the shortest path (if there is one) in less than O(n^2) ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a beginner, but I'm actually looking for an efficient solution :/

Comment: The complexity is nlogn if c++ priority_queue or a heap is used.

Comment: @CLU we can't tell you an efficient solution if we don't know all the rules.

Comment: I think I explained everything I could. Are you looking for anything specific or my description is not so clear ?

Comment: @CLU the important imformation is a) which nodes can be travelled between. Only horizontal and vertical movement might be allowed, for example. b) how do you measure distance? You could say distance is 1 for each horizontal and vertical movement for example. Or distance could be how far apart two points are when measured with a ruler. This makes a huge difference - you may not need an algorithm at all in some cases.

Comment: a) the path starts in point A and ends in point B, on a path, you can travel from actual point to any point that is not farther than distance D. b) it is the ruler, the distance is between two points is calculated by pythagoras theorem and the shortest path is sum of the distances between points on the path

Answer (score 0):

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) explanation is sufficient for this.

Dijkstra's algorithm takes 3 inputs. The Graph, Starting node and Ending node.
To construct the graph just do this

```
For i 1..n in points
   For j i+1..n in points
      if(dist(points[i],points[j])<=D)
         add j to childs of i
         add i to childs of j
```

After constructing the graph, perform dijkstra.

Comment: Nice. Could you please show me what would it look like if I didn't construct the graph ?

Comment: You should have idea on stl priority_queue and stl custom sort for user defined data type with comparator to do this. Refer 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/push/, 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/ and 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ for code examples.

Comment: priority queue is implemented internally by balanced binary search tree. Any operation (Insertion/Deletion/Retrieval) from the priority_queue is O(log n)

Comment: Yeah, I think I know how to sort 2d points. So by modifying the sort function I can avoid constructing the graph (which would take a little more time)?

Comment: Priority queue solution for dijkstra is O(n log n). Because we pop one element from the queue n times. For this problem, at each node, to find the child nodes it takes O(n) time and leads to O(n^2 log n).. So it's better to pre-construct the graph which will guarantee a solution in O(n^2 + nlogn). O(n log n) is possible if and only if you can find the child nodes in O(1).

Comment: one more question: Dijkstra needs the weights of edges, how do I deal with it, if the distances are not integers ?

Comment: what is the trouble you face with non-integers?
You can always use priority_queue<float> or any priority_queue<yourObject> once you have a comparator function.

Answer (score 0):

The subtlety of a question like this lies in a critical definition - *what is the measure of distance in your grid?*

The are many different shortest path problems and solutions, and they are studied throughout mathematics. They are each characterised by the 'topology' of the area being searched. Consider a few distinct topologies with their own solutions:

**A one sided piece of paper**

Suppose your grid represents coordinates on a piece of paper - the shortest path is easy to find, as it is simply a straight line between those points.

**The surface of the moon**

If your grid represents locations on the moon in terms of latitude and longitude, the shortest path is an arc along the moon's surface - If you drove "in a straight line" between two points on the moon, you would be travelling in an arc, because of the moon's curvature.

**Road Intersections**

If you want to find the distance between two intersections in a grid of roads, where the traffic on each road has a different speed, and you can only travel along the roads, then you can find the shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm.

**One way road intersections**

A slight variation of the above - we only need to consider roads in one direction. There might not be any paths in this case.

**Summary**

To give a good solution, we need to understand the topology of your grid. If the distance is pythagerous's theorem than that indicates euclidean geometry (like in the piece of paper example), so the solution is a straight line.

Is it possible you mean that you can travel between any two points if the are closer than D - like flying a plane between airports, for example?

EDIT: I didn't see your comment because you didn't use @. In your case your grid is like the airports a plane can fly between. The shortest path is found using Dijkstra's algorithm - the immediate neighbours of a point are all points closer than D. Find them, represent it all as a graph, and use Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: and how do I represent the weighs of edges ?

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using the formula to find the distance between 2 points i.e sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2). This distance is always the shortest between 2 points.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't write the question correctly. I can only travel from one point to another.

Comment: Euclidean distance is only valid if you can travel diagonally between any two points on the grid and there are no blocking paths at all, which defeats the purpose of pathfinding.

Comment: I didn't write the question correctly at the first time, it wasn't clear that it's a pathfinding problem, so I edited it, I am sorry once again.